# Advice on using ThreadLocals to wrap mutable singleton objects

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-local

From [Java Concurrency in practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) Chapter 3.3.3. **ThreadLocal**

> Thread-local variables are often used  to prevent sharing in designs
>   based on mutable Singletons or global variables.

If we wrap the mutable Singleton guy in a ThreadLocal each thread will have its own copy of the Singleton ? How will it remain a singleton then ? Is this what the authors meant or am I missing something pretty obvious here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If we wrap the mutable Singleton guy in a ThreadLocal

AFAIK you do not wrap the singleton class with ThreadLocal, but the object contained within the singleton which is **mutable** or non-thread safe. As the example discusses correctly that the **JDBC Connection** is not thread safe and will require additional protection, which in turn increases contention.

So in the cases when the Singletons are used just for the purpose of sharing, then replacing those things with ThreadLocal is a good idea, as all the threads have their own Connection and no more added protection is required.

Other good example of use case of ThreadLocal is **Random** generation, if there is a single `Random` object then there is contention within threads for the **"seed"**, so if each thread has its own Random object then there is no contention any more and that makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "you do not wrap the singleton class with ThreadLocal, but the object contained within the singleton which is mutable or non-thread safe" . can you elaborate please ?

Comment: I mean the singleton is a container which you use to share the object. Like a ConnectionManager singleton will be used to share DB connection object. So you don't wrap the Connection Manager but rather wrap the Connection in ThreadLocal (Thread Confinement) and hence make the connection which was mutable and non thread safe, safe. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: yes it does make sense . I think the quote in the book is ambiguous . What do you think ?

Comment: I think the authors have tried to explain that when you are using singletons just for sharing mutable data then Threadlocals are better option. Also Singleton Pattern is more an anti-pattern for testing.

Comment: If we use thread locals, logically we will end up having multiple instances of the same shared object. So how is singleton helpful here? After all the internal objects are now in many numbers. So should we use mutable states in Singleton object? I am not getting the point of using mutable objects as Singleton. There is a pretty huge chance that some thread would modify the object's state. And in such scenario, we need to manage the thread safety by ourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap a Singleton (as a design pattern) in a ThreadLocal it will remain a Singleton. There is no big magic in a ThreadLocal, if you check the source of the ThreadLocal you just saw it. It uses a Map and uses the current thread as a key. So it is quite useless to put a Singleton (a well implemented one) in a ThreadLocal. As you only get the same Singleton in various ways.

I suppose the author means that if your design heavily using Singletons and/or global variables the ThreadLocal is a good choice if you need something unique per thread, and do not want to pass all the way down the call hierarchy. But this thing is different from a Singleton. Of course you can have a ThreadLocal encapsulated in your Singleton so it will have some thread specific state (but that I would not call a Singleton anymore)

Answer (score 0):

what I understood with this line is that when an application has been design in a manner where a Singleton class has mutable state which is being read and written by many threads will require thread safety so you need to serialize all access to that state. You may consider creating a ThreadLocal on that mutable singleton. (from the book:-)
For example, a single‐threaded application might maintain a global database connection that is initialized at startup to avoid having  to  pass  a  Connection  to  every  method.  Since  JDBC  connections  may  not  be  thread‐safe,  a  multithreaded application  that  uses  a  global  connection  without  additional  coordination  is  not  thread‐safe  either.  By  using  a ThreadLocal  to  store  the  JDBC  connection,  as  in  ConnectionHolder  in  Listing  3.10,  each  thread  will  have  its  own connection.

```
private static ThreadLocal<Connection> connectionHolder= new ThreadLocal<Connection>() {
      public Connection initialValue() {
  return DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL);
  }
 };
   public static Connection getConnection() {
     return connectionHolder.get();
     }
```